# Keeping folded regins status in VsCode in backup copy?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, settings

If I create folded lines in VSCode in a (js) file, which I collapse and save the file, the next time I open the file, VSCode remembers these folded settings in the file. On the other hand, if I copy the directory with all its contents (including the ".vscode" folder, which only contains an "extensions.json" file) to another backup location and open the directory from there, it will no longer be in the former file the selected collapsible ranges. How could I keep these settings to the file in the new location?

Comment: these things are remembered in the workspace storage of VSC (sqlite3 database), you don't copy that by copying the files

Comment: this is a... shaky thing to be interested in. I expect that it would only really be scalably feasible to implement a correct behaviour if the contents of the workspaces are exactly the same.